# MySql performance for multiple insert, open and close db connection

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a database with 20 tables.
When I must to restart the database, I need to run a script that retrieve information in my backup file and populate the database again. I must to do that once a week. So, I was wondering. I have a table comments, that is growing every day. During the restart process I have a code that to this: a loop through all comments (lets say 10000 comments), and then for each one: 1-open db connection, 2-insert values, 3-close db connection. What is the good practice to do this task, in terms of performance? If I had: 1-open db connection, 2-loop trough the 10000 comments, means, insert 10000 times and 3-close, would be better in terms of performance? In other words, is there any difference to open and close the db connection 10000 times or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Would imagine the best case scenario to be to write one large insert statement, or 2-3 large ones rather than 10k individual statements.

Comment: Why don't you use `mysqldump`? It knows how to do this efficiently.

Comment: I use mysqldump. Sometimes I need insert a new big amount of data, that will be in the backup files for the next mysqldump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the data in chunks like 100 per 10000 entries(calculate this yourself) 
Then open a transaction pool... Setautocommit to false and then perform the operations . now use next 100 entries ... And at last committee and close transaction.. Any error rollback